# Tips to show that the Random Variable $X$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)-$measurable

Tags: probability, random-variables, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $X: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, where $\forall \omega \in \mathbb R -\mathbb Q: X(\omega)=0$. 
Show $X$ is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)-$measurable function:

My ideas: 
Using the definition of measurability I could take any $C \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ and I then want to show $X^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$, but from the definition of the $X$ , all I can take away is that $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q \subseteq X^{-1}(\{0\})$ but this in no way shows measurability.

Another approach could be to take a generator $\mathcal{E}$, and prove $X^{-1}(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$. I think the biggest problem is that I have no definition of $X(\omega)$ where $\omega \in \mathbb Q$.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** using your first approach:

> Let $A  \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then consider the two cases: $0 \in A$ and $0 \notin A$. Now try using that all closed and all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are contained in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra (in particular, that it is closed under countable unions).

Comment: I am still lost. I mean if I take the case $0 \in A$: all I am able to say is that $X^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(\{0\} \cup (A - \{0\}))$. This yields $X^{-1}(\{0\})\cup X^{-1}(A - \{0\})= (\mathbb R - \mathbb Q) \cup X^{-1}(A - \{0\})$, and I do not know what to do with  $X^{-1}(A - \{0\})$

Comment: Think of what values by definition of $X$ map to $(A\setminus \{0\}) \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and then try to connect this with the hint above.

Comment: $X^{-1}(A-\{0\})= \mathbb Q$ , so then $X^{-1}(A)= \mathbb R$, which is $\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$, and then measurability immediately follows. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct thinking and close, but $X^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\}) = \mathbb{Q}$ is not quite correct. Remember, $A$ is a general subset of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I'm lost. Can you please explain. $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ and not $\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$

Comment: what is $X^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\}) = $ to?

Comment: Sorry I phrased that incorrectly. $A$ is a general _element_ of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ implying only $X^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Do you understand why? $X$ does not need to map all of $\mathbb{Q}$ into our selected $A$.

Comment: yes of course! And of course any subset of $\mathbb Q$ is measurable as a union of countable singletons. Correct?

Comment: Correct, congratulations!